# Databricks GitHub and Bitbucket integrations, credential conflict

Tags: git, bitbucket, databricks, credentials, databricks-repos

I'm migrating my files from Bitbucket to Github, but every time that I need to clone something from bitbucket and send it to GitHub, I need to create a new token to integrate the tools.

It seems that, on Databricks, when you save a Github credential, it overrides the Bitbucket credential and vice-versa.

What I'm trying to say is, is there a way to have two valid credentials for GitHub and Bitbucket without conflict with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately right now it works only with a single Git provider.
It looks like that you're linking individual notebooks into Git repository. You can simplify things by cloning the Bitbucket repository(-ies) into Github, and then only with Github. The [Databricks Repos](https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html) that was introduced this year will help you working with multiple notebooks inside the single repository.